# Is there any different way to write below code by initializing hash's key with a default value?

Tags: ruby

Write a method that returns the no of various lowercase, uppercase, digits and special characters used in the string. Make use of Ranges.

Input = "heLLo Every1"

I am making using of ranges and case method in solution provided.

Solution:

```
class String
  def character_count
    uppercase_count = 0
    lowercase_count = 0
    digit_count = 0
    uppercase_range = Range.new('A', 'Z')
    lowercase_range = Range.new('a', 'z')
    digit_range = Range.new('0', '9')
    special_character_count = 0
    each_char do |item|
      case item
      when uppercase_range
        uppercase_count += 1
      when lowercase_range
        lowercase_count += 1
      when digit_range
        digit_count += 1
      else
        special_character_count += 1
      end
    end
    [lowercase_count, uppercase_count, digit_count, special_character_count]
  end
end

if ARGV.empty?
  puts 'Please provide an input'
else
  string = ARGV[0]
  count_array = string.character_count
  puts "Lowercase characters = #{count_array[0]}"
  puts "Uppercase characters = #{count_array[1]}"
  puts "Numeric characters = #{count_array[2]}"
  puts "Special characters = #{count_array[3]}"
end
```

Code is working.

Comment: Expected output :
Lowercase characters = 7
Uppercase characters = 3
Numeric characters = 1
Special characters = 1

Comment: Please edit to state your question. If you want to improve working code you should be at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not stackoverflow.

Comment: Please read "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/128421)".

Answer (score 2):

Yes

```
class String
  def character_count
    counters = Hash.new(0)
    each_char do |item|
      case item
      when 'A'..'Z'
        counters[:uppercase] += 1
      when 'a'..'z'
        counters[:lowercase] += 1
      when '0'..'9'
        counters[:digit] += 1
      else
        counters[:special] += 1
      end
    end
    counters.values_at(:uppercase, :lowercase, :digit, :special)
  end
end

if ARGV.empty?
  puts 'Please provide an input'
else
  string = ARGV[0]
  uppercase, lowercase, digit, special = string.character_count
  puts "Lowercase characters = #{lowercase}"
  puts "Uppercase characters = #{uppercase}"
  puts "Numeric characters = #{digit}"
  puts "Special characters = #{special}"
end
```

Comment: "Yes"? Consider `counters[; case item when 'A'..'Z' then :uppercase; when 'a'..'z' then :lowercase....end] += 1`.

Comment: You can further avoid the `+=` duplication by returning just the name of the key from `case` and call `counters[key] += 1` afterwards. And I would probably return the whole hash instead of the bare numbers although that's a breaking change to the OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

You can instead use `regex` in better way as following,

```
type = { special: /[^0-9A-Za-z]/, numeric: /[0-9]/, uppercase: /[A-Z]/, lowercase: /[a-z]/ }

'Hello World'.scan(type[:special]).count
# => 1 
'Hello World'.scan(type[:numeric]).count
# => 0 
'Hello World'.scan(type[:uppercase]).count
# => 2
'Hello World'.scan(type[:lowercase]).count
# => 8
```

Comment: No regex: `'Hello World'.count("^0-9a-zA-Z")` etc.

Comment: Scanning the entire string multiple times can become slow when processing larger strings or having many character classes.

Answer (score 0):

Other option.

First, map your ranges into an Hash:

```
mapping = { upper: ('A'..'Z'), lower: ('a'..'z'), digits: ('0'..'9'), specials: nil }
```

Then initialize the recipient Hash to default `0`:

```
res = Hash.new(0)
```

Finally, map the chars of the input:

```
input = "heLLo Every1"

input.chars.each { |e| res[(mapping.find { |k, v| v.to_a.include? e } || [:specials]).first ] += 1 }

res
#=> {:upper=>3, :lower=>7, :digits=>1, :specials=>1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "Agent 007 was on the trail of a member of SPECTRE"
```

```
str.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |c,h|
  h[ case c
     when /\d/     then :digit
     when /\p{Lu}/ then :uppercase
     when /\p{Ll}/ then :downcase
     else               :special
     end
   ] += 1
  end
end
  #=> {:uppercase=>8, :downcase=>28, :special=>10, :digit=>3}
```